# Convert an array of one type into a mapped object of that type

Tags: typescript

I'm wanting to do something like this:

```
type Foo = {
    name: string;
    value: any;
}

const myFoos: Foo[] = [
    {
        name: "hello",
        value: 1,
    },
    {
        name: "world",
        value: "bar"
    }
];


function createObjectFromFooArray(foos: Foo[]) : Record<string, Foo> {  //Need to change the return type
    return foos.reduce((acc, cur) => {
        return {
            ...acc,
            [cur.name]: cur
        }
    }, {});
}


const objectFoos = createObjectFromFooArray(myFoos); 

console.log(objectFoos.hello); 
console.log(objectFoos.aaa); //Should error
```

That is - given an array of `Foo`s, I want to create a mapped object of `Foo`s, and I want that object to only contain indexes that were the `name` property of the original `Foo` array . How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues here.  One is you have to resist annotating `myFoos` as `Foo[]`, because that makes the compiler widen the `name` properties to `string`, whereas you need to keep track of the [string literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types) like `"hello"` and `"world"`.  Instead you should use something like a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/overview.html#const-assertions) to keep `myFoos` as narrowly-typed as possible:

```
const myFoos = [
  {
    name: "hello",
    value: 1,
  },
  {
    name: "world",
    value: "bar"
  }
] as const;
```

Then you can have `createObjectFromFooArray` be generic in type `T` of the elements of `foos`, where `T` is constrained to `Foo` but can be more specific.  And the return type can be a conditional mapped type that iterates over the `name` properties of `T` for keys and extracts the corresponding `value` property for each property value:

```
function createObjectFromFooArray<T extends Foo>(foos: readonly T[]) {  
  return foos.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    return {
      ...acc,
      [cur.name]: cur
    }
  }, {} as { [K in T["name"]]: Extract<T, { name: K }>});
}
```

Which behaves as you expect:

```
const objectFoos = createObjectFromFooArray(myFoos);    
console.log(objectFoos.hello);
console.log(objectFoos.aaa); // error!
```

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=29&pc=39#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-CR+VQfb9dr+ACEQA)